# How to prefetch_related() for GenericForeignKeys?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a List that consists of ListItems. These ListItems then point towards either a ParentItem or a ChildItem model via a GenericForeignKey:

```
# models.py

class List(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()


class ListItem(models.Model):
    list = models.ForeignKey(List, related_name="list_items")
    order = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()

    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey("content_type", "object_id")


class ParentItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()


class ChildItem(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField()
    parent = models.ForeignKey(ParentItem, related_name="child")
```

I want to display a list of all my Lists with their ListItems and respective ItemA/ItemB data using ListSerializer:

```
# serializers.py

class ParentItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = ParentItem
        fields = ["title"]


class ChildItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    parent = ParentItemSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = ChildItem
        fields = ["title", "parent"]


class ListItemSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    contents = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    class Meta:
        model = ListItem
        fields = ["contents"]

    def get_contents(self, obj):
        item = obj.content_object
        type = item.__class__.__name__
        if type == "ParentItem":
            return ParentItemSerializer(item).data
        elif type == "ChildItem":
            return ChildItemSerializer(item).data


class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    items = serializers.SerializerMethodField()
    
    class Meta:
        model = List
        fields = ["title", "items"]

    def get_items(self, obj):
        return ListItemSerializer(obj.list_items, many=True).data
```

How can I optimize my List queryset to prefetch these GenericForeignKey relationships?

```
# views.py

class ListViewSet(viewset.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = List.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ListSerializer
```

`List.objects.all().prefetch_related("list_items")` works but the following does not seem to work:

```
List.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    "list_items",
    "list_items__content_object",
    "list_items__content_object__parent",
)
```

I've read [the documentation on prefetch_related](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) which suggests it should work:

> While prefetch_related supports prefetching GenericForeignKey
> relationships, the number of queries will depend on the data. Since a
> GenericForeignKey can reference data in multiple tables, one query per
> table referenced is needed, rather than one query for all the items.
> There could be additional queries on the ContentType table if the
> relevant rows have not already been fetched.

but I don't know if that's applicable to DRF.

---

Edit: Some better success when I move some of the prefetching to the serializer:

```
class ListSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    def get_items(self, obj):
        return ListItemSerializer(obj.list_items.all().prefetch_related("content_object"), many=True).data
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per my edit, prefetching works as intended when I move the relevant fields when they're queried in the serializer instead of cramming it all in the view's queryset.